# Python package always trying to install latest version of requirement

Tags: python, django, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I'm developing an application based on `django==1.7.x`.

The problem I have is that the `setup.py` of one of my dependencies (let's call it `foo`) specifies `Django>=1.3` as one of its requirements, but when such `foo` is being installed, it tries to install the latest version of django, which as of now is 1.8.3.

I thought that when specifying dependencies like `package>=min_version` in the setup.py file, pip would see that `package` is already installed, the installed version suffies the minimum required version and thus respect that installation of `package`.

Why is pip trying to install the latest version? and how can I force it to respect my current installed version?

**Update:** FYI, I'm using `pip==7.1.0`

**Update:** This only happens when installing manually, like `pip install foo==X.Y`. When the dependency is in a requirements file and is installed via `pip install -r requirements.txt`, installed versions of required packages are respected by pip.

Thanks!

Comment: I remember being able to do something similar to `pip install django==1.7`, maybe? You can definitely do this in `requirements.txt`: have something like  django==1.7 instead of django>=1.7

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. This happens when installing `package` manually and not through a `requirements.txt` file. If installing through requirements file, everything works fine. I'll add an update regarding this in the question :)